# Passing 'sub-domain' through ELB to server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

Context: 
I have multiple sub-domains under a domain 
example: abc.domain.com, xyz.domain.com, lmn.domain.com etc.

I have added a load balancer to my server and the server needs the sub-domain (in above eg: abc, xyz, lmn etc) to resolve to some functionality.

Issue:
What should I use so that I can achieve this functionality?

Probable solutions:
- Can I pass sub-domain name as a header from my application? 
- Can I append sub-domain as a "/path" to URL from my application and then ELB will work as per "host routing mechanism".

Answer (score 2):

The (sub)domain name requested by the browser should already be there, in the HTTP `Host` header of each request.

> Can I append sub-domain as a "/path" to URL from my application and then ELB will work as per "host routing mechanism".

No, you can't.  Per-hostname routing uses the `Host` header to select a different target group, when you have multiple *groups* or instances or services configured with multiple target groups behind one Application Load Balancer.  The path isn't modified by ALB.

Comment: I will read a little about this and will get back to you. Thanks for the help though.